# How can I best implement a weight-normalizing blend operation in opengl?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

Suppose I have a source color in RGBA format **(sr, sb, sg, sa)**, and similarly a destination color **(dr, db, dg, da)**, all components assumed to be in [0.0, 1.0].

Let **p = (sa)/(sa+da)**, and **q = da/(sa+da)**.  Note that p+q = 1.0.  Do anything you want if sa and da are both 0.0.

I would like to implement blending in opengl so that the **blend result**  =

`(p*sr + q*dr, p*sg + q*dg, p*sb + q*db, sa+da).`

(Or to be a smidge more rigorous, following https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml, I'd like f_R, f_G, and f_B to be either p for src or q for dst; and f_A = 1.)

For instance, in the special case where (sa+da) == 1.0, I could use glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); but I'm specifically attempting to deal with alpha values that do not sum to 1.0.  (That's why I call it 'weight-normalizing' - I want to treat the src and dst alphas as weights that need to be normalized into linear combination coefficients).

You can assume that I have full control over the data being passed to opengl, the code rendering, and the vertex and fragment shaders.  I'm targeting WebGL, but I'm also just curious in general.

The best I could think of was to blend with ONE, ONE, premultiply all src rgb values by alpha, and do a second pass in the end that divides by alpha.  But I'm afraid I sacrifice a lot of color depth this way, especially if the various alpha values are small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe standard blend equation can do this. At least I can't think of a way how.

However, this is fairly easy to do with OpenGL. Blending might just be the wrong tool for the job. I would make what you currently describe as "source" and "destination" both input textures to the fragment shader. Then you can mix and combine them any way your heart desires.

Say you have two texture you want to combine in the way you describe. Right now you might have something like this:

1. Bind texture 1.
2. Render to default framebuffer, sampling the currently bound texture.
3. Set up fancy blending.
4. Bind texture 2.
5. Render to default framebuffer, sampling the currently bound texture.

What you can do instead:

1. Bind texture 1 to texture unit 0.
2. Bind texture 2 to texture unit 1.
3. Render to default framebuffer, sampling both bound textures.

Now you have the values from both textures available in your shader code, and can apply any kind of logic and math to calculate the combined color.

The same thing works if your original data does not come from a texture, but is the result of rendering. Let's say that you have two parts in your rendering process, which you want to combine in the way you describe:

1. Attach texture 1 as render target to FBO.
2. Render first part of content.
3. Attach texture 2 as render target to FBO.
4. Render second part of content.
5. Bind texture 1 to texture unit 0.
6. Bind texture 2 to texture unit 1.
7. Render to default framebuffer, sampling both bound textures.